# 'CRF' object has no attribute 'keep_tempfiles'

Tags: pandas, nlp, crf

[image]

I have imported `

```
from itertools import chain
import nltk

import sklearn

import scipy.stats

import sklearn_crfsuite

from sklearn_crfsuite import scorers,CRF

from sklearn_crfsuite.metrics import flat_classification_report

from sklearn_crfsuite import metrics`
```

Is there any way we can fix this on google colab?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
!pip install scikit-learn==0.22.2 --user
```

source: https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/sklearn-crfsuite/issues/60